# trying out AGDE 2023.3.0.0 and having problems with samples not building. Is there a list of pre-reqs available anywhere?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-agde

I am trying to find an IDE that I can use to build an android game and currently looking at AGDE that is used under Visual Studio which I am familiar with.
I carried out the setup instructions and got to the step to try the samples but have got stuck and that step as I cannot get them to build.
Is there a list of versions of the pre-reqs anywhere so I can check my setup?